# window.location.replace() not working in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, modal-dialog

I'm trying to set up a login form who redirects the user to another page after submitting the form. However neither `window.location.replace()`, `window.location.href`, or `window.open()` seem to work and I can't figure out why. I checked on the developer tools and it gives me no error.

Here's the javascript:

```
function loginUtente(){

    var email = document.getElementById('loginemail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('loginpassword').value;

    var utente = localStorage.getItem(email);

    if( utente != null && JSON.parse(utente).password == password){
       window.alert("login effettuato!");
        window.location.replace("http:/www.google.it");
    }

    else{
        window.alert("Utente o password non corretti");
    }

    return false;

}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
        <form class="form-group" id="formlogin" onsubmit="loginUtente()">

            <label>Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
    <input id="loginemail" type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Indirizzo Email" required ></input>
        </div>

        <br>

        <label>Password</label>
    <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
    <input id="loginpassword" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></span> Login</button>


        </form>
```

Putting the `return false` inside the if is not working either.
The Google url is of course a placeholder url.

Answer (score 1):

In the form tag you missed to add return statement :

```
 <form class="form-group" id="formlogin" onsubmit="return loginUtente()">
```

So, form is submitted without waiting for response of function. and function code is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the submit button type attribute value from 'submit' to 'button' and use document.querySelector('.form-group').submit()

This is based on an assumption that you are using the click event with the button.